# How to explain 'rendering, painting, loading and scripting' performance in chrome devtool

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Anyone can help me to explain the concept of 'rendering, painting, loading and scripting' in chrome devtool's performance table?

'scripting' means the cost of javascript code ?

'rendering ' means the cost of layout elements ?

'painting' means painting elements on webpage ?

'loading' ?

Anyone can help ? or give me some link or article about those concepts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome DevTools - Performance Tab Summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922993/chrome-devtools-performance-tab-summary)