# How to get Page Rendering & Painting time of Chrome Devtools via Devtools Protocol?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

[image: Summary]

Chrome Devtools offers these times in Summary Section of Performance tab. I want to get these values programmatically via [CDP](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) or any other tool.

There is a [Performance.getMetric](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Performance/#method-getMetrics) API in CDP but it does not directly provide these numbers. There are some JS based solutions available like listening to `onLoad` event to get page rendering time but I wanted to first check if these values can be fetched from CDP or calculated via metrics it already provides in its Performance API.

Comment: Devtools UI calculates this chart from the data produced via performance recording. While there may be a dedicated CDP command to get the overall page metrics, but devtools doesn't use it because the statistics needs to be shown for a selected timeline range.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes I know that. I even have the performance trace data exported as json programmatically but I need to know how is the data used to calculate these values. Want to implement the logic at my end. I tried exploring the chrome-devtools-frontend github repo but not able to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @wOxxOm I found this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922993/chrome-devtools-performance-tab-summary?rq=2

I can use the events list mentioned for each section. The sum of "duration" of these events will be my corresponding value right?

Comment: @wOxxOm Can you please help