# How is Loading, Scripting, Rendering, Painting time calculated?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

On the Summary tab of Performance panel, total time taken by the browser for each category is displayed -

[image: Performance Summary]

How are these times calculated? I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61936705/7352883) SO answer as well as [source code](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/blob/main/front_end/panels/timeline/TimelineUIUtils.ts) and can see that there are some events mapped to each category. I have Chrome performance trace dump and when I calculate the sum total of durations of these events for each category, the numbers don't match.

Can someone please help me with the calculation of these values? Or any other way to programmatically fetch them?

Answer (score 0):

## # Update 3

I fully rewrote my code, here's a better solution with comments.

```js
// Import `Puppeteer` library
const Puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function CapturePerformanceMetrics(url) {
  // Launch browser and create page
  const Browser = await Puppeteer.launch();
  const Page = await Browser.newPage();

  // Navigate to URL
  await Page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

  // Evaluate Performance Metrics: The function then evaluates performance metrics inside the browser context using `page.evaluate()`. It accesses the `window.performance.timing` object to calculate various timing metrics
  const PerformanceMetrics = await Page.evaluate(() => {
    // Get timing
    const Timing = window.performance.timing;

    // Return loading, scripting, and rendering time
    return {
      LoadingTime: Timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd - Timing.navigationStart, // PageDOMLoaded - BrowserNavigated = Loading Time
      ScriptingTime: Timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd - Timing.domInteractive, // PageDOMLoaded - PageIsFullyParsed = Scripting Time
      RenderingTime: Timing.loadEventEnd - Timing.domInteractive // PageLoaded - PageIsFullyParsed = Rendering Time
    };
  });

  // Print them
  console.log('Loading time:', PerformanceMetrics.LoadingTime.toFixed(2), 'ms');
  console.log('Scripting time:', PerformanceMetrics.ScriptingTime.toFixed(2), 'ms');
  console.log('Rendering time:', PerformanceMetrics.RenderingTime.toFixed(2), 'ms');

  // Close browser
  await Browser.close();
}

// Example usage
const Url = 'https://example.com'; // URL

CapturePerformanceMetrics(Url)
  .then(() => console.log('Performance metrics captured')) // If no issue
  .catch(Error => console.error('Error when capturing performance metrics:', Error)); // If error
```

###### Notes

- In the current example `https://example.com`, there's no script on site, so scripting time would be 0
- I can't find a way to calculate Painting Time

Comment: Does the Performance metrics returned contain Loading, Scripting, Rendering & Painting times?

Comment: Also , Performance.clearMarks, Performance.clearMeasures, Performance.start doesnt seem to be valid cdp commands

Comment: Thanks for your  updated answer. Can you please point to some documentation or link which proves this calculation is correct? Because I have already tried various methods but nothing matches exactly with Devtools UI when I import the trace dump in it. Also can you please show how to calculate Painting time?

Comment: I updated it again.

Comment: If I want to capture these metrics only for a specific action, then? In the sense that I need a way to enable/start the recording , perform an action and then stop the recording. And calculate values only for this recorded interval.

Comment: And then I really don't know how.